# SocketIO volatile emit to namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

The following is failing with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'volatile' of undefined` (i.e. `map` doesn't have a volatile emit method):

```
io = require("socket.io").listen(server)
map = io.of "/map"

temp = []

recieveDataFromSomewhere = (hit) ->
  temp.push hit

setInterval ->
    map.volatile.emit 'data', temp
    temp = []
, 1000
```

I need to use volatile messages as the overhead of SocketIO keeping track of receipts is causing latency to rise problematically over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you can emit volatile messages to the namespace. Try emitting to the socket connected on the namespace.

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

var map = io.of("/map");

map.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.volatile.emit('data');
});
```

If you want to send to all connected clients you could do something like:

```
Object.keys(io.nsps['/map'].connected).forEach(function(socketID) {
    io.nsps['/map'].connected[socketID].volatile.emit('data')
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. This doesn't solve my problem however as I'm emitting data while in a `setInterval` loop (I'm building a middleware application to connect a raw firehose to clients over SocketIO), I'll update my question.

Comment: In that case you may need to map the connected sockets and volatile emit to each one.

Comment: Can you elaborate/expand on that suggestion? Perhaps an implementation example? I've updated my question highlighting how the temporary data array is emitted

Comment: Looks like the volatile method isn't exposed to `io.to()` either, so you can map the connected sockets and manually volatile emit to each. I've updated my answer with an example. Edit: Example emits to everyone and not the sockets in the namespace, I'll try find out how to do that.

Comment: Changed the example to work with namespaces, try that.